# Load External Stylesheets with JupyterDash in Google Colab

Tags: python, data-science, data-visualization, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash

I am trying build a basic dash application using google colab and JupyterDash, but for some reason I can't seem to reference external stylesheets using JupyterDash. I have tried following a similar syntax to dash when calling the external stylesheet, but it results in the error below.

What my code looks like:

```
external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/somewhat-random-code/pen/QWdrZGQ.css"]

app = JupyterDash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)    

app.layout = html.Div(id="main-container",children=[
html.Div(id="visuals-container", children=[

    html.Div(id="slider-container", children=[
        dcc.Slider(
            id='my-slider-1',
            min=0,
            max=len(daysList)-1,
            step=1,
            value=0,
        )
    ]),


    html.Div(id="map-container", children=[

        html.Div(id="result-graph")

    ]),


]),


html.Div(id="info-container", children=[
    html.Div(id='slider-output-container')
]),
```

])

What it outputs:

[image: what it looks like]

This is what it should look like using the external stylesheet:

[image: What it should look like]

I am trying to add an external style sheet to be able to customize the dash slider component at the top's colors to better match the theme of the application. I just can't seem to get dash to read the stylesheet. I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: When I run your code in colabtory, it doesn't show an empty graph like the first image attached, just a slider. when I change app.layout() to something else, the stylesheet is referenced correctly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Just a quick question,  is your dash app built using dash or JupyterDash. If it's JupyterDash, would you mind posting the first few lines of your code where you create the app = JupyterDash and where you reference the external stylesheet. Is your external stylesheet in an assets folder. Thank you.

Comment: I don't make alliterations in Dash all the time. My working environment is jupyterlab, so I use JupyterDash for verification.